# Fixed point iteration for function $\sin x^{100}$

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose that the fixed point iteration for the function $\sin x^{100}$ converges to the fixed point 0.
Determine the order of convergence with justification.

I may have misunderstandings for this question.

1) Is it right to let $f(x) = \sin x^{100}$ and the fixed point iteration be $p_n = f(p_{n-1})$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

2) Let $f(x)=\sin x^{100}$, then any n-th derivative of $f(x)$ evaluated at $0$ is $0$.

Edit: im wrong, there are non-zero terms, but how should i show that the $100$-th derivative has non-zero term and the first to $99$-th derivatives are $0$ at $0$?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $\sin(x^{100})$ is $100 x^{99}\cos (x^{100})$  by the chain rule.  If you differentiate that $99$ more times there will be a term $100!\cos(x^{100}) \neq 0$

Comment: I see, how should i write it in a proof? Also, can u address my concern (1) as well? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is the fixed point iteration the problem is talking about.  Did I read the question correctly as referring to $\sin (x^{100})$ and not $(\sin x)^{100}?$  Mine would be the usual way to read it.  To do a real proof you would have to differentiate it another $99$ times and show all the other terms have a factor $x$.  This is the only one that survives.  Informally you can argue what happens with the product and chain rules to say that all the other terms will have a factor $x$.  That should be acceptable.

Comment: Hmm, im not sure about the proper way to show the proof, do you mind if you could write one here? please :)

Comment: I would differentiate $100x^{99}\cos(x^{100})$ by hand and point out that all the terms will look like this.  Every time you differentiate the trig function you get another factor $x^{99}$, so every term except this one will have at least one factor of $x$ in the $100$th derivative.  Every time you differentiate the power of $x$ it reduces by $1$.  $99$ reductions gets you there and $\cos 0=1$